# django query with filtered annotations from related table

Tags: django, orm, left-join

Take books and authors models for example with books having one or more authors. Books having cover_type and authors having country as origin.

How can I list all the books with hard cover, and authors only if they're from from france?

`Books.objects.filter(cover_type='hard', authors__origin='france')`
This query doesnt retrieve books with hard cover but no french author.

I want all the books with hard cover, this is predicate #1.
And if their authors are from France, I want them annotated, otherwise authors field may be empty or 'None'.
e.g.:
`

```
Bookname,     covertype, origin
The Trial,    hardcover, none
Madam Bovary, hardcover, France
```

`

Tried many options, annotate, Q, value, subquery, when, case, exists but could come up with a solution.

With sql this is so easy:

`select * from books b left join authors a on a.bookref=b.id and a.origin=france where b.covertype='hard'`
(my models are not books and authors, i picked them because they're django-docs' example models. my models are building and buildingtype, where i want building.id=454523 with buildigtype where buildingtype is active, buildingtype might be null for the building or only 1 active and zero or more passive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Book id in Auther table.then your query will be like this: Author.objects.filter(origin="france",book__cover_type="hard")

Comment: Same query. That doesnt bring hard cover books with authors from germany.

Comment: for that you can use query: Auther.objects.filter(origin="germany").exclude(book__cover_type="hard")

Comment: Funny, i think shoukd write a different query for every country. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it with subquery, outerref, exists, case, when, charfield...too many imports for a simple sql.
`

```
author = Authors.objects.filter(bookref=OuterRef('id'), origin='France').values('origin')

books = Books.objects.filter(cover_type='hard').annotate(author=Case(When(Exists(author), then=Subquery(author)), default='none', output_field=CharField())).distinct().values('name','cover_type','author')
```

`